# How to hide s3 bucket and access key credentials from fluentd config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fluentd

We are sending the logs from on-prem servers to the S3 bucket by using Fluentd. The below code configuration is from my Fluentd config file.

So wondering is there a way to mask/hide/secure our sensitive information like aws_key_id, aws_sec_key, and s3_bucket from the Fluentd config file? Please advise. Thanks!

````
  @type s3

  aws_key_id YOUR_AWS_KEY_ID
  aws_sec_key YOUR_AWS_SECRET/KEY
  s3_bucket YOUR_S3_BUCKET_NAME
  path logs/

  <buffer>
    @type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/s3
    timekey 3600  # 1 hour
    timekey_wait 10m
    chunk_limit_size 256m
  </buffer>

  time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H
</match>```
````

Comment: Can you not use environment variables instead e.g. `"#{ENV['AWS_KEY_ID']}"`?

Comment: See https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file#embedded-ruby-code.

Comment: And please note that the bucket name is certainly not sensitive information, that bucket needs to have permissions set up in a way that it is irrelevant who knows of the bucket name. Only the secret / access key needs protection.

Answer (score 1):

Use the shared credentials section to specify the profile name or path to the credentials file. By default "default" is the profile name and the path points to "#{user.home}/.aws/credentials".
https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-s3/blob/master/docs/credentials.md

The bucket name looks to be mandatory

```
<match *>
  @type s3

  <shared_credentials>
    path         PATH
    profile_name PROFILE_NAME
  </shared_credentials>
</match>
```